# How to convert a json response into a callable object in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, class, object

I'm trying to convert the json response below in `$response` variable to a callable function like `$response->getStatus()` so it can return `failed`.

Here's the response

```
$response = '{
  "status": "failed",
  "msg": {
    "success": true,
    "license": "invalid_item_id",
    "license_limit": 2,
    "site_count": 2,
    "activations_left": 0,
    "price_id": false
  }
}'
```

I found something about using LazyJsonMapper.
Please how can I go about it. Thanks

Comment: Why a function specifically? Why not just a property - which json_decode provides as standard? It would achieve the same thing

Comment: Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7dbc74baa90aa432cd90d0198abc28aa476a29ad - it's trivial if you use a property.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ADyson. I already know about this method. There's a system I'm working with that already has codes in place so when JSON response comes in, it would pick the variables like $resp->getStatus() instead of $resp->status

Comment: Ok. And how does this system do that currently when it receives JSON? Do you have the source code? It must be somehow merging the data into an object which has such a function. Also...are you required to be compatible with this existing code or something? Otherwise it just seems a bit pointless to try and implement this, there's nothing wrong with using properties.

Comment: Create a class where you pass in the json data. Then you add the getters you want that just reads from that json data. It's a very trivial thing to do and since you say that you already know how to access the properties, I don't really get where you're stuck?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The problem is I don't know where to start

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT:

I recently discovered you can use `stdClass()` to get the effect you want that is similar to an array:

```
<?php

    $stdClass = new stdClass();
    
    $stdClass->var1 = "Example of stdClass()";
    $stdClass->var2 = "Another Example";
    $stdClass->HelloWorld = "Hello World!";
    
    # Just like array you can do:
    print_r($stdClass);
    
    # Or do this:
    foreach($stdClass as $std){
        echo $std, PHP_EOL;
    }
    
    # Just access the variable the same way you declared it:
    echo $stdClass->HelloWorld;
```

SandBox for example: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/e1f5a

---

### OLD:

You can use the extract function to basically get what you want, like so:

```
class status{
    private $json;
    public $getStatus;
    public $getMsg;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->json = '{
            "status": "failed",
            "msg": {
                "success": false,
                "license": "invalid_item_id",
                "license_limit": 2,
                "site_count": 2,
                "activations_left": 0,
                "price_id": false
            }
        }';

        $array = json_decode($this->json, true);
        extract($array);

        $this->getStatus = $status;
        $this->getMsg = $msg;
    }         

    # If you want your parentheses you can just do this
    public function getStatus(){
        return $this->getStatus;
    }
}

$s = new status;
print_r( $s->getStatus().PHP_EOL );
print_r( $s->getStatus.PHP_EOL );
print_r( $s->getMsg['license_limit'].PHP_EOL );
print_r( $s->getMsg['license'].PHP_EOL );

# Results:
#
# failed
# failed
# 2
# invalid_item_id
```

Live Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1e70ff642e93d77d85bd9780ecf5d9fa8f88819

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What if I want to call $s->getMsg()->getLicense() ?

Comment: Yea no that wont work; you will have to manually set it up like I did declaring the variable/function  `getLicense`. Just extremely simpler to call the array as it should be with brackets IMHO

Comment: Even then though, `getMsg()` will have to return an object and yea that is all extremely complicated for something as simple as calling an array